# OCR recognize text in a specified zone?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using pytesseract to recognize a code from contract images and the code is in the same location in the different images. The problem I'm having is I must recognize the whole image which I'm sure will take more time than recognizing a specified zone. Is there a solution to recognizing the code in a specified zone without scanning the whole image?

Thank you

Comment: select-a-part-of-a-image-using-python  using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496394/how-can-i-select-a-part-of-a-image-using-python ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8119089/will-jackson Thank you for editting, My English is not good